# When I use the concat on two datasets, one of them, has several missing data even after being treated. how to proceed?

Tags: python, join, merge, concatenation

It´s just a normal concat

df_both = pd.concat([df1,df2] , axis=1)

The booth doesn´t have missings, but after the concat the of right stay with missings NaN

Comment: if something is missing in your table it can show Nan. If you dont want to shjow Nan value then replace it

Comment: This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339886/pandas-concat-generates-nan-values

Comment: please post an example of a `concat` with missing data for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example